# Display the details entered into the form in console - disable submit until valid

Tags: javascript

When the submit button is clicked, the browser's console should neatly display the details entered into the form but The submit button should not be functional and should look disabled as long as the required fields are not filled in.

```js
const inputEl = document.querySelector(".input");
const nameEl = document.querySelector(".name");
const numberEl = document.querySelector(".number");
const emailEl = document.querySelector(".email");
const commentEl = document.querySelector(".comment")
const hourEl = document.querySelector(".hour")


myForm = [nameEl, numberEl, emailEl, commentEl, hourEl]
inputEl.addEventListener("click", () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < myForm.length; i++) {
    console.log(myForm[i].value); // this is work!


  }
});

let formValue = {}
inputEl.disabled = true

myForm.forEach(change => {
  if (formValue === myForm.value) {
    inputEl.disabled = false;
  } else {
    inputEl.disabled = true; //  when i put this code to disable the butten its work but its cancel the first one
  }
})
```

Comment: `myForm.value` doesn’t exist. In this `forEach` method, _`change`_ is the element. You never use it. And `formValue` is an empty object. What do you expect it to be equal to? You may also want [`some`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) or [`every`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) instead, since currently, your `forEach` statement is equivalent to `inputEl.disabled = true;`, and even if fixed, only applies to `hourEl.value`.

Comment: I made a snippet Please add the form

Comment: Also please delegate the clicks if you need them